# Solaris x86 11.1 and qlt driver -- only 3/4 ports attach

Tags: storage, solaris, zfs, fiber, openindiana

I'm using the QLogic QLE2564 4-port 8Gb HBA.  The problem I have is that when I attach the qlt target mode driver to the card, only 3/4 ports attach the driver.

```
ffffc10006854e58 pciex1077,2532, instance #0 (driver name: qlt)
ffffc10006854b80 pciex1077,2532 (driver not attached)
ffffc100068548a8 pciex1077,2532, instance #2 (driver name: qlt)
ffffc100068545d0 pciex1077,2532, instance #3 (driver name: qlt)
```

Those three ports do work.  I've tried switching just instance #1 to the qlc driver (which should be an ok thing to do) but it causes a different port to have the driver not attached.  There is always one port with the driver unattached.  Also if I configure it that way I get intermittent kernel panics from qlt.

Anybody with qlt knowledge?  Qlogic recommends using the bundled Solaris drivers for Qlogic cards, but they say they do not support the qlt driver so they won't say if there is a possible problem with the card itself.  If I use the qlc driver all the ports show up as normal.

Thanks